# I encountered an error that could not find the npm and node on the server. /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux, vue.js, centos, nuxt.js

While I was developing, I thought I needed to update the node, and I downloaded it again after deleting the node.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f

sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.0.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

It looked like it was going smoothly, and I checked the node.

However, the console was floating `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`.

I tried `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` but the problem was not solved.

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/node’: File exists
```

I tried `ln -s --f /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` too.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Check the path and verify if you are able to see the node in the path.
Step 2: Close the terminal and open a new terminal and do the step 1 again
Step 3: If still not available in path, go to the node installed folder and try to update the path variable with the node location.
Step 4: Do step 1 again.